# Unity Score does not increase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public static int score;        // The player's score.
Text text;                      // Reference to the Text component.
void Awake ()
{
    // Set up the reference.
    text = GetComponent <Text> ();  
    score = 0;
}
void Update ()
{
    // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
    text.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

This is Score manager class i need to increase my score but the score is always zero

```
public void decrease() {
    if (current () > 1)
        tm.text = tm.text.Remove (tm.text.Length - 1);
    else {
        ScoreManager1.score+=scorevalue;
        Destroy (transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
}
```

And this code is that increase the score
I create a canvas and wantto change score belong canvas's text
 canvas text has `scoremanager1` script

Comment: So what value does the `scorevalue` variable hold? Did you do some logging sothat you can see that it definetly reaches the `else` statement in `decrease()`?

Comment: my initialize is public int scorevalue=10

Comment: Place a `Debug.Log("Score: {1}", ScoreManager1.score);` before and after the `ScoreManager1.score+=scorevalue;` expression and observe the log.

Comment: i solved i changed my scorevalue variable's name monodevelop really weird

Comment: Does "else" in if statement even happen? What are the values of "current()"?

Answer (score 0):

For best practice Object Orientated Programming, you shouldn't publicly expose your score variable. This is because you lose control over the value it can be set to. For example; if you had a public class exposed and were setting it's value to something, in most cases you would want to disallow a value of null, as all follow up action on the class would then return a NullReferenceException.

For what you're trying to achieve however, you could use a class with a static method attached. As you can see below, the score and text values are stored statically, and the value of text is got on Awake. We then use the static method AddScore to set the value of score (clamping it's value to 0 and the maximum value of an integer), before setting the text property of text field.

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static  int     m_score;
    private static  Text    m_text;

    public void Awake()
    {
        m_text  = GetComponent<Text>();
        AddScore(0);
    }

    public static void AddScore(int p_score)
    {
        m_score = Mathf.Clamp(m_score + p_score, 0, int.MaxValue);
        m_text.text = "Score: " + m_score;
    }
}
```

Similarly you could add more static methods for SetScore, ResetScore, and any other functionality you required.

Hope this helped some people, if want a slightly different approach, you could also look at [static classes versus singletons](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlayerPrefs to assure that you save your scores. 
Playerprefs use to save data (string,integer and  etc.) in internal device.
On your situation,it should be like this.

```
  public void Start(){

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
                // Set up the reference.
                m_text  = GetComponent<Text>();
                m_score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score",0);
            }
  public static void AddScore(int p_score)
    {

        m_score = Mathf.Clamp(m_score + p_score, 0, int.MaxValue);
        m_text.text = "Score: " + m_score;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", m_score);

    }
```